# Modify ggdist interval thickness?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’m visualizing some distributions with the [ggdist](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/) package and would like to modify the width of the interval lines. For example, a basic plot created with `stat_histinterval()` creates a histogram with an interval at the bottom.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

set.seed(123)

dist <-
  tibble(p_grid = seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 1000),
         prior = rep(1, times = 1000)) %>%
  mutate(likelihood = dbinom(4, size = 15, prob = p_grid),
         posterior = likelihood * prior,
         posterior = posterior / sum(posterior)) %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 10000, weight_by = posterior, replace = TRUE)

ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
  stat_histinterval(.width = c(0.67, 0.89))
```

[image]

What I would like to do is make the black interval lines thicker. From the documentation, it seems like the `interval_size` argument is what I need. However, specifying an interval size overwrites the entire interval (i.e., it looks like one interval instead of a 67% and 89% interval).

```r
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
  stat_histinterval(interval_size = 5)
```

[image]

And specifying multiple sizes to the `interval_size` argument errors out.

```r
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
  stat_histinterval(interval_size = c(5, 10))
#> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (34): interval_size
```

Is there a way to modify the interval's thickness while preserving the presence of multiple intervals?

<sup>Created on 2022-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument for this is `interval_size_range` which for some reason is only documented on [`geom_slabinterval`](https://mjskay.github.io/ggdist/reference/geom_slabinterval.html) despite working in other functions:

```
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
    stat_histinterval(.width = c(0.67, 0.89),
                      interval_size_range = c(1, 3))
```

[image: Plot with thicker interval]

To eliminate the giant point, you want to change the default value of `fatten_point` which expands that point. For some reason, `fatten_point` also affects the size of the interval, so you'll need to increase the `interval_size_range` to compensate with a matching line size:

```
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
    stat_histinterval(.width = c(0.67, 0.89),
                      interval_size_range = c(2, 5),
                      fatten_point = 1)
```

[image: Plot with thicker interval without giant point]

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use two interval statements?

```
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
  stat_histinterval(.width = .89, interval_size=10) + 
  stat_interval(.width = .67, interval_size=10, col="black", show.legend=FALSE)
```

[image]

The problem is that there is a bit of overplotting.  You could just add all of the individual elements:

```
ggplot(dist, aes(x = p_grid)) +
  geom_histogram(fill="gray55") + 
  stat_interval(.width = .67, interval_size=10, col="black", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  stat_interval(.width = .89, interval_size=5,col="black", show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data=dist, aes(x=mean(p_grid), y=0), col="white", inherit.aes = FALSE, size=5)
```

[image]